# bootstrap: how to drag text from dropdown select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning how to implement drag and drop and have a select dropdown form. This dropdown displays several options and i would like the user to be able to drag the option text into another box.

According to the [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) all I have to do is `set the draggable attribute to true`.

I have tried the following but dragging does not seem to work:

```
<div class="container">
    <label>My List</label>
        <select class="form-control">
           {{#each my_list}}
               <option value="{{this}}" draggable="true">{{this}}</option>
           {{/each}}
        </select>
</div>
```

I have also tried using jquery UI by doing this:

```
<div class="container">
    <label>My List</label>
        <select class="form-control">
           {{#each my_list}}
               <option value="{{this}}" id="draggable">{{this}}</option>
           {{/each}}
        </select>
</div>

<script>
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
</script>
```

Any ideas would be most helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Check this from w3Schools itself:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Just `set the draggable attribute to true` won't work. You have to do more.

What's happening here:

When you start dragging `drag(event)` called and it saves it's ID through [dataTransfer.setData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData). And when you drop over the rectangle,  `drop(ev)` gets the element by previously saved ID and append it to itself. So it will be in that rectangle.